# Is it possible to have a searchable input table column in html5, pulling data from sql database? If so, how?

Tags: sql-server, database, html

Please forgive me if I don't explain it very well as I do not have any knowledge on database, nor html to be honest.

I am trying to make a webpage that can pull client name from database,and user can search for the client name they want and input other info for each client selected.

I believe I have very limited access to the database itself and the only place I can see the data is via Visual Studio. After connecting to the database in Visual Studio (xxxx.net), it shows xxxx.dbo, where under it I can see the tables.

May I know if it is possible to pull the data if I only have read-only access to the .dbo file? I was able to create a table with add/delete row functions with the help of google.

I might not have to finish the whole project if I could create a webpage and show that this works and is a better way than updating the client drop-down list in 60+ Excel files (different lists) every month.

Comment: this is a borad and vague question. you cannot access a database with plain html, you need 'something' to interact with the db and output the result to the client. that's what asp.net, php and other tools are for.

Comment: I am using Aptana for this and I do understand that I would need other tools to access the database. I guess my first concern is if I am able to pull the data with just read-only access, next is how to reference the db only knowing the path showing up on visual studio, and lastly how to successfully do that.

Comment: Your best bet is a tutorial for base steps. Unfortunately this question is so broad that cannot be answered properly on a q&a site...

Comment: To get myself started, what would you recommend me to do now? Like which tools, language, or anything helpful. Hopefully, I could ask a better/more specific question once I know more.

It is confusing to me since I have no knowledge in 2 things html & database, versus just googling specifics about how to do something on Excel VBA before.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry OP I misread your question, I didn't realize you were looking for a .NET answer only. Yes this is still equally as possible using ASP.NET, you will just have to generate the HTML on the fly like so:

```
public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Populating a DataTable from database.
            DataTable dt = this.GetData();

            //Building an HTML string.
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            //Table start.
            html.Append("<table border = '1'>");

            //Building the Header row.
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<th>");
                html.Append(column.ColumnName);
                html.Append("</th>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");

            //Building the Data rows.
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                html.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }

            //Table end.
            html.Append("</table>");

            //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetData()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerId, Name, Country FROM Customers"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will give you a good enough starting point to get going. Also note, when connecting to the server it is considered best practice to do it like such:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
SqlConnectionStringBuilder b = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
b.DataSource = "190.xxx.xxx.xxx\ServerName";
b.InitialCatalog = "DataBaseName";
b.IntegratedSecurity = false;
b.UserId = "...";
b.Password = "...";
conn.ConnectionString = b.ConnectionString;
conn.Open();
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for answering! Please excuse my "noobness", but I didn't realize I was looking for a .Net answer. From my googling research, I thought I need to use either Javascript/php to do this.

I am using Aptana. Do you think I am able to use this code? If not, would you have any suggestions on how I should approach this?